# Issue with Sharepoint 2013 with workflow 2010 sending email to external email

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow

I have anonymous website made on SharePoint 2013, there one of the list where anonymous user can add item then I have make SharePoint 2010 workflow to send email. But it stuck on "**In Progress**". On the same time another workflow works nicely with out any error.

After comparing both workflow I found that first work is sending email to external email id's and second workflow sending email within corporation. So that is the reason second workflow working.

Now Kindly help me that how can I send email to external email from SharePoint 2010 Workflow from SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 1):

If you have assigned the **external email to SP user** then you can send the email with 2013 workflow.
But you can't send email to hard coded email id like Anonymous user's email.

For that, you need to **add the users to AD/SP Users** and **assign the External Email Id to that profile** and then can you **send email**.

Or you can have another option of **2010 workflow.**
Hope it will help you.

Comment: I am using 2010 workflow already

Comment: Are you using the same server? IIS is configured on the Server where Emails are not sending?

Comment: Yes, IIS is on same server

Comment: Both the workflows are Designer 2010 workflows?
Share those in question.

Comment: Yes, Both workflow are developed in Designer 2010

Comment: Did you got the solution for the same?

Comment: No I did not found solution